# I have a background image set to cover, but there is still padding? how do i remove it?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to have a background image set to cover the entire screen of the website, however there seems to be about 3-5 pixels of padding/white space no matter what i do.  Can someone help me fix this?

here is the css i used:

```
    .body{
      position: relative;
      background: url(images/home-bg.png) no-repeat center center scroll; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden!important;
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
      padding: 0 0 0 0;
      border: 0px;
      display: block;
      box-sizing: border-box;
     }
```

Comment: and here's where you can see what i'm talking about [link](http://www.pulvercreative.com/woobyclip)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css file

```
body{
margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a margin of 8px on the `<body>` element (not the div with an ID of body).

add this to your css

```
body {
   margin : 0;
}
```